# unapplied patch reinstall the drupal core

Tags: installation, composer

I've upgraded a site from d8 to d9. And I'm rewarded with this error :

```
- Applying patches for drupal/core
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-03-15/claro_theme_is_incompatible_with_the_themable_forms_module-3203745-1.patch (Claro theme is incompatible with the Themable Forms module)
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-03-15/claro_theme_is_incompatible_with_the_themable_forms_module-3203745-1.patch
```

I've manually applied the patch but could not tell it to composer. Therefore when I want to install a module, composer reinstall the core everytime.

Is there a way to put in vendor/composer/installed.json the installed patch ?

Comment: You are fixing the wrong problem. Adjust the patch so it can be applied automatically, but don't break composer!

Comment: This got fixed and commited to 9.2.x and 9.3x as per the issue queue [https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3203745](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3203745). Therefore, you don't need to patch anything if you have the latest D9 version.

Comment: That was necessary in Drupal 8. In Drupal 9, the patch won't apply simply because it has been already applied, as @NoSssweat said.